# Why am I getting file not found error even when file is in that location? Does it has to do something with the file path not given properly?

Tags: android, properties-file

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /RecordsKeeper/address/src/main/res/config.properties: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I am getting the above error while I run my application. I am not able to load my config.properties file from config.java while I'm running my android application. Although it gets loaded and works fine when I run my library test cases using that config file.

Comment: Does the java process have rights to access to the file too?

Comment: Java classes in the library folder have the access to the config file. I am not able to figure out if the java classes in the app folder have the access or not.

Comment: That file is not in your Android device but on your pc. No wonder an Android app cannot 'find' it.

Comment: How should I proceed now? Any help would be appreciated.